# SQL Oracle query to find receipts

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table which is called PURCAHSE

it contains

```
PurchaseNo
ReceiptNo
ServiceType
PaymentType
GST
Amount
ServedBy
ClientNo
```

Each of the receipts are from a book that is identified by the first numbers of the receipt number e.g. 444555 is from book number 444

I want to find the number of purchases, but only if there has been at least 10 other purchases from that same receipt book.

I understand I will have to use a COUNT aggregate. The way I was thinking I would need to go, for each purchase P in PURCHASE, I would need to go over all the other purchases and find the ones with the same 3 digits as  P's ReceiptNo.

How Can I do this? I am unsure of the syntax

The expected output should be

the expected output would be a single integer, of the number of purchases that have the same first 3 digits from their receipt number

Comment if you need more details

Thanks

Comment: Please add some sample data and expected output.

Comment: @techdo the expected output would be a single integer, of the number of purchases that have the same first 3 digits from their receipt number

Comment: Is the receipt number stored as a character or a numeric type field? Can it ever be less than 100000 or more than 999999?

Comment: @MarkBannister It is defined as RECEIPTNO NUMBER(6), when creating the table

Comment: Incidentally, combining two different pieces of information into a single field is a violation of first normal form - your current problem illustrates one aspect of why this is a bad idea, as do the issues arising from my previous comment.

Comment: @MarkBannister Are you suggesting that a better output would be lets say, 12     446655  where 12 is the number of purchases that have a receipt number of 446? And so on for other receipt numbers?

Comment: I am suggesting that receipt book number should be a separate field on your PURCHASES table, with receipt number being solely the remaining digits that do not identify the book.

Comment: @MarkBannister I see, this is the way it got set up, not willing to change it at this point, do you see another way around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
select trunc(ReceiptNo/1000) BookNumber, count(distinct PurchaseNo) NumPurchases
from PURCHASE
group by trunc(ReceiptNo/1000)
having count(distinct PurchaseNo) >= 10
order by 1
```

Comment: Well on that one, i got 618 Rows returned, shouldn't be that many i believe

Comment: @Jim: Have you **checked** any of them? Also, as I asked previously, **can the ReceiptNo ever be less than 100000 or more than 999999?**

Comment: Yeah there is only one occurrence of each receipt number, i just don't remember having that many different ones..., are you sure that code isn't getting the first 3 and last 3 digits?

Comment: And no it can't be less than 100000 or more than 999999

Comment: @Jim: First, try running `select count(*) from PURCHASE` - if the result is less than 6180 then obviously there is something wrong. Next, take the first book number returned from the query in the answer and try checking that book number against the query table - so if the first book number returned was 100, try `select(*) from PURCHASE where ReceiptNo between 100000 and 100999` - if 10 or more purchases are returned then that particular book number is correctly selected. Try something similar for a few other book numbers chosen at random.

Comment: Yeah I got 9999 from count(*) purchase, and yeah I tried 676 and got 13, so I guess that is correct afterall, since 676 in the table returned 13. Thanks mate, big help.

Comment: I tried your edit just then, has them in order, 618 rows selected again, so I think that is what I'm looking for afterall... be a challenge to report this haha

Comment: To make things simple is there anyway I can sum the number of purchases here? and just return that value?

Comment: @Jim: Does `PurchaseNo` uniquely identify each PURCHASE record? If so, just stick the query in the answer (without the `order by 1`) inside a set of parentheses, and run a query like `select sum(NumPurchases) from ` *parenthesised query*.

Answer (score 0):

If you're INFS2200 student, you cannot use `group by` plus `having` for task4.1. If you do so, you will see index not used in the task4.2. Try it without the `group by` clause and use a subquery instead.